# Excel IF Statement Change

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

```
=IF(B638=B637,IF(AJ638=0,0,(AJ638-AJ637)*AE638),AJ638*AE638)
```

Above is a working IF statement.
I'm having trouble adding another IF statement; when I do I'm receiving an error stating that I've used too many arguments.

What I'm needing to tell Excel is the following:

I'm having issues with the FALSE value of the 2nd IF statement, being:
`(AJ638-AJ637)*AE638`

I want to add another IF statement there stating that IF A637="CASH" then replace the subtracting `AJ638-AJ637` part of the formula with the following substraction: `AJ638-AJ636`.

I've tried a couple of different options and I'm receiving errors. I'm wondering if I need to restructure the entire format of the spreadsheet at this point.

Comment: Why would you not post the expression that fails?  That would make it much easier to fix.  No doubt you have your parentheses incorrectly placed.  Pretty sure this will be deemed of topic being only a cell formula rather than a VBA macro.

Comment: Someone had edited the formula. Originally, I had that section in bold...

The formula as it sets above works fine, I'm not getting any argument errors. I'm needing to add that additional bit of logic to it and can't figure out how to get it in there.

Comment: It's better to post some sample data and examples of required outcomes with that data. You can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post a table in your question.

Comment: `=IF(B638=B637,IF(AJ638=0,0,IF(A637="CASH",(AJ638-AJ636)*AE638,(AJ638-AJ637)*AE638)),AJ638*AE638)` ?

Comment: Understood.  The edit placed it in plain text as it should be, but failed to remove the bold  markup.  I see no reason for that sub-expression needing to be bold in any event.  What were you trying to indicate by that?

Comment: @P.b reads minds.  I have no idea how he got to that from your question! Maybe it is right, but it would have been useful to get the question right.  It is not clear, and it is not programming. Voting to close. Suggest https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel

Comment: @Clifford Formulas are on topic here.  It is considered a form of programming, and some can get quite complicated.

Comment: @P.b you solved it. I tried my best to explain what I was trying to do. Thank you. Thanks for the table tip as well.

Comment: @ScottCraner Given that a tag exists for that I'd have to concede that it appears to be accepted as on topic. It is still not "_about programming or software development_" by any definition.  I do not see how _complexity_ alone qualifies anything as on-topic here.  Lots of things are "quite complicated", that are not programming.  If not for that reason, lack of clarity is sufficient.  Now a fortunate guess been made in a comment, no doubt the OP won't be motivated to fix it.

Comment: @Clifford here is a meta discussion on it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-spreadsheet-formulas-on-topic

Comment: @ScottCraner yes I was just reading that.  I don't have to agree, but I won't in future vote to close for that reason. It is not my server-space ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the part of the formula you need the extra statement on in `IF(statement,new_outcome,old_part)`.

So what you're trying to accomplish is:

> If `A637="CASH"`
> Then (new_outcome) `(AJ638-AJ636)*AE638`
> Else (old_part) `(AJ638-AJ637)*AE638`

So what you're after is:

`=IF(B638=B637,IF(AJ638=0,0,IF(A637="CASH",(AJ638-AJ636)*AE638,(AJ638-AJ637)*AE638)),AJ638*AE638)`